# How to make AngularJS refresh header after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created web-application, in which there is a redirect after login to welcome page, but the header is not updated in this case.
Here is my Angular code:

```
MyApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        login();
        var name = "";
        if (document.cookie.indexOf("name") !== -1)
            name = document.cookie.split('=')[2];

        $scope.menu = [
            {
                title: 'Product',
                url: 'product'
            },
            {
                title: 'About',
                url: 'about'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                url: 'contact'
            },
            {
                title: name,
                url: 'welcomeUser'
            },
            {
                title: 'LogOut',
                url: 'logout'
            }
        ];

        $scope.refresh();
    };
});

MyApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    var name = "";
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("name") !== -1)
        name = document.cookie.split('=')[2];
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("name") === -1 && (name === "" || name === undefined)) {
        $scope.menu = [
            {
                title: 'Product',
                url: 'product'
            },
            {
                title: 'About',
                url: 'about'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                url: 'contact'
            },
            {
                title: 'Register',
                url: 'register'
            },
            {
                title: 'Login',
                url: 'login'
            }
        ];
    } else {
        $scope.menu = [
            {
                title: 'Product',
                url: 'product'
            },
            {
                title: 'About',
                url: 'about'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                url: 'contact'
            },
            {
                title: name,
                url: 'welcomeUser'
            },
            {
                title: 'LogOut',
                url: 'logout'
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

Angular config code:

```
MyApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/404'
        });
});
```

And here is my JS code for POST request sending - login user function:

```
function login() {
    var username = document.getElementById('usernameLogin').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('passwordLogin').value;

    if (!username.trim() || username.length === 0 || !password.trim() || password.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById('wrong_username').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('wrong_password').style.display = 'block';
        return;
    }

    var json = {
        username: username,
        password: sha1(password)
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhosts:7777/account_management/login_user",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "true") {
                document.cookie = "";
                document.cookie = "username=" + username;
                window.location.href = "/#/welcomeUser";
            } else if (data === "false") {
                document.getElementById("wrong_password").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                alert(data);
            };
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

The *authorization* itself works fine, but `$scope.menu` updates only after page refresh.

*Is there any ideas how to fix it?*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MainController` ad `LoginController` are two different controllers and are having different scopes.

Changing `$scope.menu` in one doesn't change in another as they don't have any parent child relationship.

You must either have the menu in `$rootScope` and then update it in the respective controllers after login.

```
MyApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.menu = [];
});

MyApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.menu = []; // update the menu
});
```

Else, have it as a service so that you can use `$emit` event and in it to update the menu once the user has logged in.

The `function login() {...}` must be part of a service. You must avoid using `jQuery` in an angular project. Use `$http` inside service which is preferable and provides same functionality as `$.ajax`

Comment: Update : Why you use `$rootScope` in the both controllers? you can use a $scope in Main controller, and you can use `$rootScope` in  Login controller

Answer (score 9):

Instead of having your menu in `$rootScope`, you could use event to warn your menu that the user has logged in and that he should reload itself.

On LoginController

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('userLoggedIn');
```

On MainController

```
$rootScope.$on('userLoggedIn', function () {
    //Code to apply modification to your menu
});
```

If you have to pass parameters, you can use the second argument of `$broadcast` method like this :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('userLoggedIn', {key: 'value'});

$rootScope.$on('userLoggedIn', function (params) {
    console.log(params.key); //value
});
```

Comment: I did know about the *broadcast* concept. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1 :

You need to use `$rooteScope` for call scope variables from another controller.

Please use `$rooteScope.objectName` in your login controller instead of  using`$scope.objectName`.

Like

**// Assign the menu details on scope variable in main controller**

```
MyApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.menu = [
            {
                title: 'Product',
                url: 'product'
            },
            {
                title: 'About',
                url: 'about'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                url: 'contact'
            },
            {
                title: 'Register',
                url: 'register'
            },
            {
                title: 'Login',
                url: 'login'
            }
        ];
});
```

---

//**then call the scope variables via rootScope from login controller**

```
MyApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope,$rootScope ) {
  $rootScope.menu = [
            {
                title: 'Product',
                url: 'product'
            },
            {
                title: 'About',
                url: 'about'
            },
            {
                title: 'Contact',
                url: 'contact'
            },
            {
                title: 'Register',
                url: 'register'
            },
            {
                title: 'Login',
                url: 'login'
            }
        ];
});
```

### Solution 2

Your `window.location.href = "/#/welcomeUser";` is a javascript code, So it is not consider the scope objects

You need to change   `window.location.href = "/#/welcomeUser";`
 to  `$location.path('/#/welcomeUser');`

also you need to configure the `$location` on your controller

### Solution 3

If above two solutions are not working, you need to manually reload the page by using `$route.reload()`

But the third solution is not good, because it will make a page reload. But it's solve your issue to manually reload the screen.